# How to implement Wi-Fi deauthentication attack on mac

Tags: wifi, macos, deauth-attack

I am trying to send "de-authentication requests" with Mac but all the previously used tools don't work

1. I was using [`bettercap`](https://www.bettercap.org/) before, now it says that deauth packet
   was sent but nothing is actually happening to my own devices, so I
   have to manually reconnect to wifi for it to capture a handshake
2. Also one of the popular options was using `JamWiFi` GUI, which does
   not work either and throws an error, which is discussed in this
   [`issue`](https://github.com/0x0XDev/JamWiFi/issues/24)
3. Tried also with `scapy` library in python, which also does not send
   those requests

Is there any way to send it and how?

Comment: Are you _absolutely positive_ you are transmitting on the same channel as your target devices? It can get a bit confusing when both 2.4 and 5 GHz are in play.

Comment: Yes I do. Also as a proof of concept, using the same methods in other OS ( Linux/Windows ) works

Answer (score 1):

Use aircrack-ng suite for deauth attack. Below is the example command and ref. link

**aireplay-ng -0 1 -a 00:14:6C:7E:40:80 -c 00:0F:B5:34:30:30 ath0**

-0 means deauthentication
1 is the number of deauths to send (you can send multiple if you wish); 0 means send them continuously
-a 00:14:6C:7E:40:80 is the MAC address of the access point
-c 00:0F:B5:34:30:30 is the MAC address of the client to deauthenticate; if this is omitted then all clients are deauthenticated
ath0 is the interface name

https://www.inkyvoxel.com/wi-fi-deauthentication-attacks-using-aireplay-ng/

Comment: It does not work either. Command executes successfully but does absolutely nothing, when I set `0` to send packets continuously it still just executes the command and finishes